# MATLAB: detect and remove mirror imaged pairs in 2 column matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, vectorization, detect

I have a matrix

```
[1 2
 3 6
 7 1
 2 1]
```

and would like to remove mirror imaged pairs..i.e. output would be either:

```
[1 2
 3 6
 7 1]
```

or

```
[3 6
 7 1 
 2 1]
```

Is there a simple way to do this? I can imagine a complicated for loop, something like (or a version which wouldn't delete the original pair..only the duplicates):

```
for i=1:y
    var1=(i,1);
    var2=(i,2);
    for i=1:y
        if array(i,1)==var1 && array(i,2)==var2 | array(i,1)==var2 && array(i,2)==var1
            array(i,1:2)=[];
        end
    end 
end
```

thanks

Comment: Note that you are using `i` as a loop index for both loops, that will not work. I'd also argue caution against [using `i` as a variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How's this for *simplicity* -

```
A(~any(tril(squeeze(all(bsxfun(@eq,A,permute(fliplr(A),[3 2 1])),2))),2),:)
```

Playing [`code-golf`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_golf)? Well, here we go -

```
A(~any(tril(pdist2(A,fliplr(A))==0),2),:)
```

If dealing with two column matrices only, here's a *simpler* version of `bsxfun` -

```
M = bsxfun(@eq,A(:,1).',A(:,2)); %//'
out = A(~any(tril(M & M.'),2),:)
```

Sample run -

```
A =
     1     2
     3     6
     7     1
     6     5
     6     3
     2     1
     3     4
>> A(~any(tril(squeeze(all(bsxfun(@eq,A,permute(fliplr(A),[3 2 1])),2))),2),:)
ans =
     1     2
     3     6
     7     1
     6     5
     3     4
>> A(~any(tril(pdist2(A,fliplr(A))==0),2),:)
ans =
     1     2
     3     6
     7     1
     6     5
     3     4
```

Comment: @randomGuy 3D weed! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here a not so fancy, but hopefully understandable and easy way.

```
% Example matrix
m = [1 2; 3 6 ; 7 1; 2 1; 0 3 ; 3 0];
```

Comparing m with its flipped version, the function `ismember` returns `mirror_idx`, a 1D-vector with each row containing the index of the mirror-row, or 0 if there's none.

```
[~, mirror_idx] = ismember(m,fliplr(m),'rows');
```

Go through the indices of the mirror-rows. If you find one "mirrored" row (`mirror_idx > 0`), set its counter-part to "not mirrored".

```
for ii = 1:length(mirror_idx)
    if (mirror_idx(ii) > 0)
        mirror_idx(mirror_idx(ii)) = 0;
    end
end
```

Take only the rows that are marked as not having a mirror.

```
m_new = m(~mirror_idx,:);
```

---

Greetings