# Numpy or python filter data set for reciprocal relationships

Tags: python, numpy

I have a data set that I need to filter and am not even sure how to approach the problem. Here is an example data set:

```
Id1     Id2
1006    1244
1006    1245
1006    1246
1244    1006
1245    1006
1246    1006
...     ...
```

The data represents relationships between two people. I do not need to retain both sides of the relationship. So, if I have a relationship between 1006 and 1244, I do not also need a relationship between 1244 and 1006. So I need to filter out all of redundant relationships with numpy/python. Any ideas?? Set_index and map?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [numpy_indexed](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP) package can be used to solve such problems efficiently (disclaimer: I am its author).

Assuming A is an array containing both columns:

```
import numpy_indexed as npi
npi.unique(np.sort(A, axis=1))
```

Comment: Thanks Eeclo. I get the following error after installing and trying this: `import numpy_indexed as npi
  File "C:\...\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy_indexed\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from numpy_indexed.arraysetops import *
  File "C:\...\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy_indexed\arraysetops.py", line 7, in <module>
    from builtins import *
ImportError: No module named builtins `

Comment: Rather confusingly, the 'builtins' module comes from the 'future' package. Thanks for the feedback; I should fix that in my pip packaging! Until then, a manual pip/conda install should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

If `A` is the `2-column` `2D` array, here's an approach using `NumPy broadcasting` inspired by this [`other solution for a MATLAB question`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34910545/3293881) -

```
A[~(np.triu((A[:,None,0] == A[:,1]) & (A[:,None,1] == A[:,0]))).any(0)]
```

One can also use the very efficient [`scipy's cdist`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.17.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html), like so -

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

out = A[~np.triu(cdist(A,A[:,::-1])==0).any(0)]
```

Sample run -

```
In [162]: A
Out[162]: 
array([[1006, 1244],
       [1006, 1245],
       [2222, 7777],
       [1006, 1246],
       [1244, 1006],
       [1245, 1006],
       [1244, 9999],
       [1246, 1006],
       [8888, 4444]])

In [163]: A[~(np.triu((A[:,None,0] == A[:,1]) & (A[:,None,1] == A[:,0]))).any(0)]
Out[163]: 
array([[1006, 1244],
       [1006, 1245],
       [2222, 7777],
       [1006, 1246],
       [1244, 9999],
       [8888, 4444]])

In [164]: A[~np.triu(cdist(A,A[:,::-1])==0).any(0)]
Out[164]: 
array([[1006, 1244],
       [1006, 1245],
       [2222, 7777],
       [1006, 1246],
       [1244, 9999],
       [8888, 4444]])
```

Answer (score -1):

```
set(map(sorted, dataset))
```

if dataset is big and you are using python 2 prefer a generator comprehension instead of map